# Display info bottom margin of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

how can i display information in red frame like below of visual studio?

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mL2d.png

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Text Editor

[image]

Comment: I have config but still can't see, now I'm using visual studio 2022.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF8ga.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yefy6.png

*sorry, i can't post the image*